# what is the equivalent of EventLog of ASP.NET 2.0 in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I created a project in ASP.NET 2.0 where for my custom Error Handling function I could use `EventLog.WriteEntry("mysite.com",message,entryType)`
But now I am building a project in ASP.NET 4.0 and this class is not found here ! I am confused whether I've missed it somehow or there is an equivalent of it.

Comment: It should be there. Does your project have a reference to System.dll? Does your source file have `using System.Diagnostics`?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same even in 4.0 as per MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzwc042w.aspx

It still lives in System.Diagnostics namespace